# Add a Web Part inside the Script Editor?

Tags: web-part, html

Ok, I know. Weird question.

Is there any way to add a Web Part inside the Script Editor? i.e. Code Web Parts as HTML?

The reason being, I've got a Script Editor webpart, that I use to format all of my content. It's going great - but i'd like to put the site feed in amongst my HTML. Is there a way to do this?

**If not:** Is there a way to use SharePoint Designer to code my divs so that one third of that div container has my HTML and then the last two thirds contains my SiteFeed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot exactly insert the web parts inside that script editor of yours, but you can definitely use HTML to show the site feeds. Simple feeds in the form of rows can be used using some HTML table structures (insertRow(), etc.)

Otherwise, you can write out the entire HTML code with your Site Feed scripts and div stylings, in a different file and upload in your site, and link its path within your script editor.

**[Edit]** You can practically do any HTML related stuffs with your Script Editor. In this case, I've embedded a  tag within HTML to answer your question. However, unfortunately you cannot insert List/Libraries webpart directly within it. You will have to think of some customized CSOM solutions for this

[image]

Kindly mark this as an answer if this helps you.

Comment: Ok. How about other Webparts? Such as embedding video nestled within my HTML or even lists?

Comment: @Anniesoptera - there.. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can always change the layout of the SitePage or inscert a table into a Wiki Page and place you webpart to the relevant parts. 
e.g.

1. Site Page Layout config:
   [image]
2. You can always develop your own Page Layouts [Guide from MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-create-a-page-layout-in-sharepoint)
3. Also, you can place a Site Feed on the page and write a custom javascript which will wrap the Site Feed container with some additional HTML after the page is loaded. If you are familiar with javascript -it would be an easy task for you :)